# How can I run an extracted .exe in WINE?

Tags: wine, executable

I have a program called BridgeM1. It is a front-end for the arcade music emulator M1. I read at the following link ( [M1 and .lst files](http://forums.bannister.org/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=5645&PHPSESSID=3c74d06c904029be10e5bfea6062aeab) ) that I could use this program in WINE. The problem is I'm not sure how to run it. It did not come with an installer. To run it under Windows, you just had to extract the files into a folder and then double-click the .exe to run it. I tried setting the file permission "Allow file to be run as executable" in Properties but when I right-clicked it and ran it with Wine Windows Program Launcher, it displayed a window at the bottom of my screen saying "Opening bridgem1.exe" and then after a few seconds nothing happens. Double-clicking the file only displayed a brief terminal window which promptly closed. Do I have to extract the file where my WINE folder is at?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your console :

WINE /path/to/your/exefile

Then press Enter, there might be some important informations which can be logged in the terminal.

Nikos

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the following message in the terminal: `wine: cannot find '/home/[my_user_name]/Music/m1_Player/bridgem1.exe'`